# Problems on SAML configuration with Tableau Online

Tags: python, tableau-api, saml

I am trying to configure a SAML connection for Tableau Online. I am using pysaml 2 to achieve that. The first part of the configuration goes well, Tableau seems to find my IdP just right, i enter my credentials, but then the login crash.
The fact is that Tableau awaits for a signed answer apparently, which is not sent by pysaml.
Here is the error i have:

```
Response nor included Assertion is signed], displayableMessage=[null], exceptionClass=[null]
```

After some research, i found that this is linked to:

```
Identity Provider does not sign SAML assertions.
Verify your IdP configuration.
```

After diging in code, i can find that the certificate present in authnrequest is NOT detected by pysaml2idp. So he does not put the certificate in the response, and so, my SP is not happy about it.

this is the saml authnrequest:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ns0:AuthnRequest xmlns:ns0="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:ns1="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https:/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx" Destination="https://auth.my-numii.io/sso/post" ForceAuthn="false" ID="a114ce90gdg6h2ff1beie36g2jjffj7" IsPassive="false" IssueInstant="2018-06-28T07:30:43.296Z" ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Version="2.0"><ns1:Issuer>https://sso.online.tableau.com/public/sp/metadata?alias=ea962d84-5953-435d-a6db-71090a3b3e25</ns1:Issuer><ns2:Signature><ns2:SignedInfo><ns2:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /><ns2:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" /><ns2:Reference URI="#a114ce90gdg6h2ff1beie36g2jjffj7"><ns2:Transforms><ns2:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" /><ns2:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /></ns2:Transforms><ns2:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" /><ns2:DigestValue>mb4DBX4olvq8tZFtq+zMgSOcBLPjNxi+VbLCyKsaH20=</ns2:DigestValue></ns2:Reference></ns2:SignedInfo><ns2:SignatureValue>T4AK7DNDJ4pMrXB8ndmzXtvyN6RM7sjuAQ9q9l6l4+0P7mdw3JZ3TQKjB9sgwDEwb9Y4ILOrxjELUWLTV7kSXFai8a+E6j241Djmqw+LgzvLXBKFLgamVeizise78cE9WWjZonSOc0MNPYUyTdognFAlREasKkV6Rv6j4wkHu98=</ns2:SignatureValue><ns2:KeyInfo><ns2:X509Data><ns2:X509Certificate>MIICozCCAgygAwIBAgIGAWQ15g7DMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMGwxOzA5BgNVBAsMMmNvbS50YWJs
ZWF1c29mdHdhcmUuc2l0ZXNhbWwuY29yZS51dGlsLkNyeXB0b1V0aWxzMS0wKwYDVQQDDCRlYTk2
MmQ4NC01OTUzLTQzNWQtYTZkYi03MTA5MGEzYjNlMjUwHhcNMTgwNjI0MDc0MzQ2WhcNMjgwNjI1
MDc0MzQ2WjBsMTswOQYDVQQLDDJjb20udGFibGVhdXNvZnR3YXJlLnNpdGVzYW1sLmNvcmUudXRp
bC5DcnlwdG9VdGlsczEtMCsGA1UEAwwkZWE5NjJkODQtNTk1My00MzVkLWE2ZGItNzEwOTBhM2Iz
ZTI1MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDOrUrIzIyKD6hTQBWdxLVtztLXlQIgvEXp
ICdpuSVGZKga+zxcxB9s0qiDN4nYaS9MAYCxnZDO8aiM2Kx5VPygpyv0Vmh/9Ryq61BCEAuVgjNP
OvN158Qw3yGE3pPaGXkPLjCFc6kpdcKakjTB/kHpyZPRRpDnu6xYemO0fEWq/wIDAQABo1AwTjAM
BgNVHRMBAf8EAjAAMB0GA1UdDgQWBBS9YsmNneD8YD3mhYNHs42pQ3MQ9jAfBgNVHSMEGDAWgBS9
YsmNneD8YD3mhYNHs42pQ3MQ9jANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFAAOBgQANA3+/sAu7pxI2lmRVDNiiA8wK
YfFuVImZXe1+12priFeOVJuwKCMTfUXPM0rZ+Ktl803uBFPhpnzWCd25vnU/PgMEyISGNw72wzt4
az7z1O7PlLDEPjGCHCE/aHv/HNnJAMKK+hzJ9XPBgk2wLFixa3YOAbZ2FPQ1gurNBfJaiA==</ns2:X509Certificate></ns2:X509Data></ns2:KeyInfo></ns2:Signature></ns0:AuthnRequest>
```

I think I am missing something here. Is there any "tricks" to sign my answer to Tableau Online?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple certificates get passed back-and-forth depending on if you're using TLS/SSL transport, signing messages, encrypting portions of the message, etc. The key is to know which cert is used by whom for what.

The certificate sent within the authnrequest (SP->IdP) is used by the IdP to verify the signature within the request itself -- that is, to verify the request has not been tampered with.

That part appears to be working (from your description), as your IdP prompts for login and attempts to respond. (You mention that the certificate is not "detected" by the IdP & this may simply be that the IdP simply chooses not to verify the signature of the request.)

Since your SP is looking for a signed response, the IdP uses its own certificate, and will / should send the x509 certificate back (IdP -> SP), where the SP can verify the signed response. (Similar to the SP->IdP request, the SP could choose to ignore verifying the signature in the response, but sounds like your SP is requiring signed responses.)

So, this appears to be an IdP configuration issue: it should, but is not, sign the response with its (the IdP's) certificate.